# callback when AudioContext is ready

Tags: html, html5-audio, chromecast, web-audio-api

I used this to create an audio context:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
myAudioContext = new AudioContext();
```

It is taking about 2-3 seconds before any sound can be produced.  Is there a callback to tell if the audio context is ready?

Edit more detail:

This is on a Google Chromecast device.  I believe it has a version of Chrome browser.  I tested on others browers (Desktop Chrome, Mac Safari).  It has no delay.

I have a class file called webaudioclass.js that contained this.

```
var time1 = 200;
var delay = 2;
var gainZero = 0.0;

function webaudioclass() {
    console.log('webaudioclasss init');
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    myAudioContext = new AudioContext();

}

function webaudioclassPlaySoundC() {
    var mySource = myAudioContext.createOscillator();
    var myGain = myAudioContext.createGainNode();
    mySource.frequency.value = 261.625549;
    mySource.connect(myGain);
    myGain.gain.value = gainOne;
    myGain.connect(myAudioContext.destination);

    mySource.start(0);
    setTimeout(function(s) {
               myGain.gain.value = gainZero;
               s.stop(delay + myAudioContext.currentTime);
               }, time1, mySource);

}

webaudioclass.prototype.playSoundC = webaudioclassPlaySoundC;
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? As far as I'm aware, the AudioContext should be ready to go as soon as you create it.

Comment: Also, what OS and audio hardware you're running on.

Comment: @KevinEnnis:  added more detail.

Comment: @cwilso: added more detail.